# Qt Creator c++11 syntax highlighting for generic projects

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt-creator

My core question is, when using Qt Creator as a code editor for "generic" (non-Qt) projects, **how do I tell it to use c++11 syntax highlighting?**

I have a c++11 project I've been working on for awhile, and I decided I'd give Qt Creator a try. This is a plain vanilla c++ project, with a hand-coded makefile and so forth.

Qt Creator opened up the project ("eSLIME") just fine, and created three files: eSLIME.config, eSLIME.includes and eSLIME.files. It did not create a .pro file.

It seems not to recognize c++11 calls. For example, it underlines "`#include <unordered_set>`" in green, and indicates that there is no such file or directory.

I suspect I'm supposed to put something in the .config file, but I can't figure out what and google searches aren't helping. I tried appending -std=c++0x, which didn't work.

PS: The code is too broken to build right now, which is why I was switching to an IDE.

Comment: Did you try adding the respective directory in your eSLIME.includes file? E.g. unordered_map is located in /usr/include/c++/4.4/ on my system. That's a path to be added so that QtCreator will parse it.

Comment: Still, it would be nice to get it to work natively, as I tend to work across platforms with different versions of C++. :)

Comment: Just update Qt Creator to the most newest version

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53481748/how-to-set-c-standard-in-qtcreator-with-clangcodemodel-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt 5.0.2 support c++11 syntax for any c++ file then

just download [QT](http://qt-project.org/downloads) 5.0.2 ( Qt Creator 2.7.0 included).

Comment: Thank you, Meysam and fasked!

Answer (score 13):

2 years passed from this question and answers, but nothing changed in *Qt Creator* (at least for linux): even newest version (now it's 3.5) can't parse C++11 headers.

The problem is that by default `__cplusplus` in internal *Qt Creator* parser is defined to some value less than 201103L, there are a lot of checks of this macro in STL headers, something like this:

```
#if __cplusplus < 201103L
#include <bits/c++0x_warning.h>
// disable all tasty functionality
#endif
```

Firstly I tried adding to ***.config** the following line:

```
#define __cplusplus 201103L
```

Nothing happened.

After some investigations I finally found proper solution: just write in ***.config**:

```
#define __cplusplus 201103
```

Magically everything becames alive!

Comment: is this .config file generated by QT?

Comment: @BenJones it is usually generated by Qt Creator when you create a project there. I suppose that it is not CMake-based or Qbs-based project.