# How to enable C++11 support in generic project in Qt Creator 2.8.0?

Tags: c++11, qt-creator

I know that Qt Creator can recognize C++11 in Cmake and QT projects, but how to activate it in generic projects (e.g. created by "import existing project" option)? It's not enabled by default (e.g. autocomplete doesn't work for C++11 classes such as `std::shared_ptr` etc).

Comment: The problem is not solved for me yet, because I was not able to compile QT Creator from source.

Comment: C++11 support was added in Qt Creator, but by default syntax highlighting and autocompletion is disabled (at least in 3.5 version for linux). I answered about this issue in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924040/qt-creator-c11-syntax-highlighting-for-generic-projects).

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed quite a while ago for the 3.0 release: https://codereview.qt-project.org/#change,62536

This should be working now just fine as per the Gerrit comment:

> Generic project manager: assume C++11 for cxxVersion.

Comment: That's good news, but I don't want to wait several months :) BTW I've tried to build it from source and it failed: `ui_blackberrydeviceconfigurationwizardsshkeypage.h: No such file or directory`. Also qmake complains about some missing headers: `Project WARNING: The plugin depends on private headers from QtDeclarative module`. Do you know where I can find those headers? I've downloaded QT source, but it doesn't contain them either.

Comment: @lizarisk: http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/10/23/qt-creator-3-0-beta-released/

Comment: It still doesn't solve the problem, C++11 features are disabled by default.

Comment: @lizarisk: enable it!

Comment: How? I've installed the beta but still don't have C++11 support.

Comment: I don't have any .pro files, only .creator and .config