# How to set C++ standard in QtCreator with ClangCodeModel plugin?

Tags: c++, qt, ide, clang, qt-creator

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I have already tried almost everything and am banging my head against a wall right now..

The problem is, QtCreator 4.8.0-beta for Windows with Clang Code Model plugin parses my project 
as C++98 whereas in fact it is C++17. However specifying the standard version explicitly in the settings dialog is not allowed ("Option "-std=c++17" is invalid").

So, how do I tell ClangCodeModel that it should parse code as C++17?
I use CMake for building the project and have `set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` in the top-level CMakeLists.txt file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is similar to
[This one](https://bugreports.qt.io/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/QTCREATORBUG-20574), According to the link, dated October 2018, it is an issue of QtCreator and does not seem to have been solved. However I would suggest you to test yourself the solution proposed in the link, infact it may work on your pc.
If you are still stuck into this problem, try to install the latest version of Qt 5

Comment: It would be more useful to quote the "solution proposed in the link" into the post, in case the link rots.

Comment: @user202729 You are right, but the point is that the link does not propose a solution and it sems to be a bug of Qt. On the other hand I don't know hot to quote it

Comment: Thanks for the link. Updating to the latest version didn't help unfortunately. I guess we'll have to wait for the fix.